# InMobi Banner Ads Opening in Phonegap InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, inmobi

I am trying to add [InMobi](http://www.inmobi.com) ads into my Phonegap application. The problem is, some of the ads open in the phonegap browser rather than redirecting to the phone's built in browser. Here is the code for implementing the ads. Any ideas on how I could redirect these links?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var inmobi_conf = {
    siteid : "HIDDEN",
    slot : "15",
    sticky: "bottom"
};
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.cdn.inmobi.com/ad/inmobi.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove this permission from the config.xml and check

`<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>`

Thanks,
Shashank(InMobi)

Comment: Hi, The InAppBrowser plugin was never installed. I know this because there is no toolbar when the ads open. It is a fullscreen of ads blocking my app.